# issues saving changes with Directus

Tags: directus

I'm noticing some issues that aren't happening in the demo. I haven't started customizing anything yet other than populating the database.

If I change the project logo in global settings i get an error:
Argument type should be in array (identifier, literal, select, value)

```
[2020-05-01 16:33:29] api[trisev].ERROR: Directus\Validator\Exception\InvalidRequestException: collection: This value should not be blank. in /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Services/AbstractService.php:186
```

Changing collection layout was when I first noticed this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNNpy.gif)

The log I get after changing the layout:

```
[2020-05-01 16:33:29] api[trisev].ERROR: Directus\Validator\Exception\InvalidRequestException: collection: This value should not be blank. in /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Services/AbstractService.php:186
Stack trace:
#0 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Services/AbstractService.php(120): Directus\Services\AbstractService->throwErrorIfAny
#1 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Services/AbstractService.php(398): Directus\Services\AbstractService->validate
#2 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Services/ItemsService.php(188): Directus\Services\AbstractService->validatePayload
#3 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Services/ItemsService.php(341): Directus\Services\ItemsService->validateParentCollectionFields
#4 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Services/CollectionPresetsService.php(62): Directus\Services\ItemsService->update
#5 /var/directus/src/endpoints/CollectionPresets.php(89): Directus\Services\CollectionPresetsService->update
#6 [internal function]: Directus\Api\Routes\CollectionPresets->update
#7 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(40): call_user_func
#8 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(281): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke
#9 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Application/Http/Middleware/AbstractRateLimitMiddleware.php(34): Slim\Route->__invoke
#10 [internal function]: Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\AbstractRateLimitMiddleware->__invoke
#11 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#12 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#13 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#14 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Application/Http/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php(124): Slim\Route->Slim\{closure}
#15 [internal function]: Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\AuthenticationMiddleware->__invoke
#16 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#17 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#18 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#19 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Application/Http/Middleware/TableGatewayMiddleware.php(25): Slim\Route->Slim\{closure}
#20 [internal function]: Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\TableGatewayMiddleware->__invoke
#21 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#22 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#23 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#24 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Application/Http/Middleware/DatabaseMigrationMiddleware.php(15): Slim\Route->Slim\{closure}
#25 [internal function]: Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\DatabaseMigrationMiddleware->__invoke
#26 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#27 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#28 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#29 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\Route->Slim\{closure}
#30 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(268): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack
#31 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(503): Slim\Route->run
#32 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Application/Http/Middleware/AbstractRateLimitMiddleware.php(34): Slim\App->__invoke
#33 [internal function]: Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\AbstractRateLimitMiddleware->__invoke
#34 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#35 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#36 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#37 /var/directus/vendor/directus/proxy-detection/src/ProxyDetectionMiddleware.php(30): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}
#38 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Application/Http/Middleware/ProxyMiddleware.php(18): RKA\Middleware\ProxyDetectionMiddleware->__invoke
#39 [internal function]: Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\ProxyMiddleware->__invoke
#40 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#41 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#42 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#43 /var/directus/vendor/akrabat/ip-address-middleware/src/IpAddress.php(113): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}
#44 [internal function]: RKA\Middleware\IpAddress->__invoke
#45 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#46 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#47 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#48 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Application/Http/Middleware/CorsMiddleware.php(71): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}
#49 [internal function]: Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware->__invoke
#50 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#51 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#52 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#53 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Application/Http/Middleware/ResponseCacheMiddleware.php(63): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}
#54 [internal function]: Directus\Application\Http\Middleware\ResponseCacheMiddleware->__invoke
#55 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/DeferredCallable.php(57): call_user_func_array
#56 [internal function]: Slim\DeferredCallable->__invoke
#57 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(70): call_user_func
#58 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(117): Slim\App->Slim\{closure}
#59 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(392): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack
#60 /var/directus/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(297): Slim\App->process
#61 /var/directus/src/core/Directus/Application/Application.php(161): Slim\App->run
#62 /var/directus/public/index.php(5): Directus\Application\Application->run [] []
```

I've used DigitalOcean's One-Click setup and enabled SSL and remote access to view the database outside of the droplet.

Any leads in the proper direction would be great. I can't find where I can set the collection layout manually either to bypass this for now so my layouts are stuck if i changed it.